# How to create a logo animation similar to TED loading icon?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, bubble-popup

How to make an animation similar to this?

A circle that appears like a bubble and then pop and show the name of the app

This is the intro animation of TED app.
I'm trying to make something similar

Are there widget to make a similar effect? or whatelse?

Expected result
[GIF IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXH0B.gif)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can try these two ways:

1. Design the animation in `Rive` and then use the `Rive` package in your
   app to implement it. This can be a good option if you are looking
   for a simpler, more lightweight tool that is specifically designed
   for creating animations for your app.

   https://pub.dev/packages/rive

   https://rive.app/
2. Design the animation in After Effects and then export it as a `Lottie`
   file. `Lottie` is a popular library that allows you to use animations
   created in After Effects directly in your app. This can be a good
   option if you are already familiar with After Effects and want to
   create more complex animations with advanced features.

   https://pub.dev/packages/lottie